# Need to get the latest file with date timestamp for each month

Tags: shell-script

I am just starting with Unix programming and I have a requirement. I have four files which are placed in my landing zone and I need the scheduler to pick up the latest file of that month and year.

For example:

```
FILE_NR_WEEKLY_01_20130528_CHARGE

FILE_NR_WEEKLY_01_20130530_CHARGE--> This needs to be picked 1st for may month

FILE_NR_WEEKLY_01_20130601_CHARGE

FILE_NR_WEEKLY_01_20130604_CHARGE -->This needs to be picked up for June month
```

In the above case for that year, month and date combination, I need to get the latest file.

Comment: Your example shows that you want to select on date-stamps incorporated in the filenames. In the title you refer to date-timestamp (as per creation time, modification time, access time)? Please disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

On the excerpt you gave, this:

```
ls -r | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk '
  match($0,"20[0-9]{6}") && !n[substr($0,RSTART,6)]++'
```

would work. The `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is only needed with GNU `awk` which doesn't recognise the `{6}` otherwise (it doesn't harm with other `awk` implementations).

With GNU `sort` which guarantees a *stable* sort,

```
ls -r | sort -ut_ -k 5,5.6
```

would also work (expects the date in the 5th field).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are only interested in the months of one or two years (say 2012 and 2013), and if you *know* that the file for the latest month is newer than those for previous months (I mean if the file for January was created *before* the file for February etc), then you can use the file's time stamp to find the newest for each year and month, just sort the files by date (`ls -tr`) and select the last file (`tail -n 1`):

```
for year in 2012 2013; do for month in {1..12}; do 
   file=`ls -tr *$year*$month??_* | tail -n 1` && 
   if [ -f "$file" ]; then echo "$year/$month $file";fi;
   done;done 2>/dev/null
```

If you cannot know that the "latest" file is also the newest, you will have to parse their names:

```
find . -type f | perl -ne 'chomp; /_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_/; 
    $newest{$1}{$2}=$_ if $3>$newest{$1}{$2}; 
    END{
       foreach $year (keys(%newest)){
         foreach $month (keys %{$newest{$year}}){
           print "$year/$month\t$newest{$year}{$month}\n"
        } } }' | sort
```